# Why StopForumSpam nuget package is not working anymore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

We are using [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StopForumSpam.Net/) successfully from years and from a week or so it simply accepts any email on our website.

The code we use in our ASP.NET MVC website to validate account registration follows.

Does anybody know what happened? Did this nuget package become obsolete?

```
if (CommonUtils.IsAvailable("http://www.stopforumspam.com", 1000))
{
   Client client = new Client("xxxxxxx");

   Response response = client.CheckEmailAddress(model.Email);

   if (response.Success)
   {
      ...
   } 
}
```

How do I know that most of the accepted email addresses are spammer? Because they are rejected by [Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/). In addition, the number of registrations is increased considerably in the last two weeks.

**EDIT**: I've also tested [this Visual Studio project](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp_Free_Code/API/Download_Stop_Forum_Spam_Net.htm) and the result is the same.

Comment: do you get a response?  Any exceptions thrown?  You should include more details about what is happening/not happening.  (...and why not https?)

Comment: Everything works fine but I know for sure that those email addresses are banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking for help on this forum, I discovered that the email addresses were registering on many websites but not spamming (yet).

https://www.stopforumspam.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=51378